# Objectify Ref.get() called twice

Tags: objectify

If I call Ref<>.get() second time, does it query datastore or uses the already loaded value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only goes to the datastore (or memcache, or whatever) once.  The value is cached in the Ref itself.